# SQL Statement - want daily dates rolled up and displayed as Year

Tags: sql, content-query-rollup

I have two years worth of data that I'm summing up for instance

> Date | Ingredient_cost_Amount| Cost_Share_amount |

I'm looking at two years worth of data for 2012 and 2013,
I want to roll up all the totals so I have only two rows, one row for 2012 and one row for 2013. How do I write a SQL statement that will look at the dates but display only the 4 digit year vs 8 digit daily date. I suspect the sum piece of it will be taken care of by summing those columns withe calculations, so I'm really looking for help in how to tranpose a daily date to a 4 digit year.
Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
select DATEPART(year,[Date]) [Year]
, sum(Ingredient_cost_Amount) Total
from @table
group by DATEPART(year,[Date])
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a range/grouping table.
Something similar to the following should work in most RDBMSs:

```
SELECT Grouping.id, SUM(Ingredient.ingredient_cost_amount) AS Ingredient_Cost_Amount,
                    SUM(Ingredient.cost_share_amount) AS Cost_Share_Amount  
FROM (VALUES (2013, DATE('2013-01-01'), DATE('2014-01-01')),
             (2012, DATE('2012-01-01'), DATE('2013-01-01'))) Grouping(id, gStart, gEnd)
JOIN Ingredient
  ON Ingredient.date >= Grouping.gStart
     AND Ingredient.date < Grouping.gEnd
GROUP BY Grouping.id
```

(`DATE()` and related conversion functions are heavily DB dependent.  Some RDBMSs don't support using `VALUES` this way, although there are other ways to create the virtual grouping table)
See [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) for why I used an exclusive upper bound for the range.

Using a range table this way will potentially allow the db to use indices to help with the aggregation.  How much this helps depends on a bunch of other factors, like the specific RDBMS used.